# how can I replace substring that occurs only once while excluding substring two or more times in a row?

Tags: java, string, replace

Is there any way that I can do the following in java ?

```
String s = "acdaaefacaa";
String b = s.replaceLikeMethod("a", "");
```

and b becomes "cdaaefcaa". Basically replace any occurrence of the first string `"a"` with the other one `""` unless `"a"` appears two or more times in a row.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to make use of a regex, but I am not experienced enough on the topic to give a sufficient answer.

Comment: just modified the case to clear anything ambiguous, I want to replace "a" that happens only once, if there are two or  more consective "aa", ignore it.

Comment: @javarookie tried to make the question clearer. Feel free to rollback if you disagree

Comment: `s.replaceAll("(?<!a)a(?!a)", "")`? http://ideone.com/V8aYjy

Comment: @zapl and I wasn't paying attention to the comments at all while writing my answer. I will delete my answer if zapl posts an answer of his own

Comment: I'm happy when someone makes a nice answer with explanations. Bad habit / laziness posting comments instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to achieve this. The features you want are

1. Negative LookBehind `(?<!foo)` Match pattern unless `foo` occurs right before.
2. Negative LookAhead. `(?!foo)` Match pattern unless `foo` occurs right afterwards

You basically need to use both at the same time with the same string as the string to match and pattern. E.g.

```
String pattern = "(?<!foo)foo(?!foo)";
```

Or to easily replace with a string known at runtime like `"a"`

```
String pattern = "(?<!foo)foo(?!foo)".replace("foo", "a");
```

Finally, to replace just do :

```
String b = s.replaceAll(pattern, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex: `((?<!a)a(?!a))`. It uses negative lookahead and lookbehind. It matches every `a` that is not preceded and followed by another `a`.

*Test:*

```
String input = "acdaaefacaa";
String output = input.replaceAll("((?<!a)a(?!a))", "");
System.out.println(output);
```

*Outputs:*

> cdaaefcaa

Comment: Curious, any reason why you put the whole pattern in (extra) parentheses ?  what's the effect of that ?

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis the effect is nothing, simply nothing.